# Listing and binding to properties of a type, not a collection of types

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a `Listbox` with property names of type Color from a `MySettings` object. I want to create another control (let's say a `TextBox`, the type is irrelevant) that binds to the *value* of property name listed.

I am at a loss as to how to achieve that. As it is now, the listbox is just a list of strings, obviously, it has no knowledge of the `MySettings` object.

One of the things I thought about is creating a collection of objects of a custom type that somehow binds to the `MySettings` object, and setting that as `ItemsSource` for the `ListBox`.

I know I trying to reinvent the wheel here, so I would appreciate any pointers to get me started.

Code-behind, `ListBox` is currently defined in xaml with no properties other than `x:Name="listBox"`

```
foreach (var prop in settings.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(System.Drawing.Color))
    .OrderBy(p => p.Name))
{
    listBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem()
    {
        Content = prop.Name,
    });
}
```

MySettings contains several properties:

```
[UserScopedSetting()]
[ConfigurationProperty(nameof(BackColor), DefaultValue = "GhostWhite")]
public System.Drawing.Color BackColor
{
    get { return (System.Drawing.Color)base[nameof(BackColor)]; }
    set 
    {
    base[nameof(BackColor)] = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

[UserScopedSetting()]
[ConfigurationProperty(nameof(ForeColor), DefaultValue = "Black")]
public System.Drawing.Color ForeColor
{
    get { return (System.Drawing.Color)base[nameof(ForeColor)]; }
    set 
    { 
    base[nameof(ForeColor)] = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to bind to the value of the selected Color only, or shall there be a TextBox per item? Besides that, consider using `System.Windows.Media.Color` as type of your settings. `System.Drawing.Color` is WinForms.

Comment: A single TextBox. The color type needs to be passed on to a WinFormsHost control, hence Drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the ListBox's ItemsSource to a collection of name/value pairs (an anonymous class here, but could as well be a regular class):

```
listBox.ItemsSource = settings.Properties
    .OfType<SettingsProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(System.Drawing.Color))
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        Value = settings[p.Name]
    });
```

Then declare a ListBox ItemTemplate that shows the Name property, and a TextBlock that binds to the Value property of the selected ListBox item:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Value}"/>
```

Comment: Your first code sample didn't work for me (it returns an empty list), but it was helpful in putting me on the right track: convert the appropriate properties to a collection of objects to use as ItemsSource for my listBox. Thanks!

Comment: I've tested it with a couple of application settings of type System.Drawing.Color.